# R compared words between documents

Tags: r, compare

I have two texts that I convert to bag of words. One bag of words for text 1, one bag of words for text 2.

I am trying to find a way to plot both those documents' words together to understand how much they are different.

One way I Was thinking is to have two barplots one over the other and see in which words (word count) they are the same and in which they differ.

I was able to launch a simple bar plot
from the guide here
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/text-mining-and-word-cloud-fundamentals-in-r-5-simple-steps-you-should-know 
(see last plot)

but I have now two bar plots that I can not directly compare.

I was thinking for example to put the words together on the same plot.
Either as two histograms one over the other or create some 2d clustering, showing areas of words that the two documents are different but also their overlapping areas.

Which package will you suggest  and procedure to compare such two bags of words?
Thanks
Alex

Comment: Please provide an example of texts so we can help you. it will be possible to create one plot to directly compare the words, if you create an appropriate dataset.

Comment: perhaps you could create a clearer question and provide sample data vs tease out the actual problem in comments to now-deleted answers?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A small snippet follows: try --help for usage information.
+ echo 'error: failed to merge robot test results: 0'
error: failed to merge robot test results: 0
+ exit 1
+ finish
+ rc=1
+ [[ 1 != 0 ]]
+ echo '********************** the error might have happend in the lines before this **************************'
********************** the error might have happend in the lines before this **************************
+ cleanup_channel_var
+ rm -rf /var/lib/eiffel-vagrant/channel_6/in_use

Comment: It's too broad for SO, I voted to close. You might get a lot irrelevant words if you just compare absolute frequencies, even with a decent list of stopwords. You might want to have a larger corpus, adding some texts about the same subject, compute a `tf-idf` and then plot terms that have the biggest `tf-idf` on either sides and compare their absolute frequencies.